# Can anybody please tell me how to optimize query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have this query below, and I am doing a lot of subqueries. Is this a good way to do it? If not can anybody please tell me how to write/optimize this query in a better way? I am trying to learn how to optimize queries better. please point me in the right direction.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      cases.case_sk 
    , cases.case_number
    , cases.lawtype_code
    , cases.closed_ind
    , cases.date_received 
    , cases.[style]
    , COALESCE ((select initials from employee where employee_sk=cases.atty1_sk),'') as 'Atty1' 
    , COALESCE ((select initials from employee where employee_sk=cases.atty2_sk),'') as 'Atty2'
    , (select description from group_items where item_sk =case_parties.role_sk) as 'Role'
    , COALESCE ((select description from group_items where item_sk =case_pick.item_sk ),'') as 'Case Type'
FROM cases
LEFT JOIN case_parties
    on case_parties.case_sk =cases.case_sk
    and case_parties.role_sk in  (select item_sk from group_items where group_code='ROLES' /*and item_sk='1312'*/)
LEFT JOIN case_pick
    on case_pick.case_sk = cases.case_sk
    and group_code='CTYPE'
```

Sample data
[image]
Thank you

Comment: I would use join instead of sub queries , It's easier to debug and udnerstand and also In some cases you can reduce number of fetching/reading from a table , in your case If you can provide sample data and desired output It can be easier to help you.

Comment: @eshirvana, I got it. I also added a sample data image. Thank you

Comment: Optimizing a query generally starts with the _actual execution plan_. From there you can divine what indexes might be appropriate to improve performance. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. Tip: For improved maintainability use table aliases on _all_ column references, even in subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

You can achieve the same by using **CTE**

```
;WITH CTE_case_parties AS(  SELECT *
FROM case_parties
INNER JOIN group_items ON case_parties.role_sk =item_sk
where group_code='ROLES')

SELECT DISTINCT 
  cases.case_sk 
, cases.case_number
, cases.lawtype_code
, cases.closed_ind
, cases.date_received 
, cases.[style]
, CASE WHEN employee_sk=cases.atty1_sk THEN initials ELSE'' END as 'Atty1' 
, CASE WHEN employee_sk=cases.atty2_sk THEN initials ELSE'' END as 'Atty2'
, CASE WHEN item_sk =case_parties.role_sk THEN description END as 'Role'
, CASE WHEN item_sk =case_pick.item_sk  THEN description ELSE'' END as 'Case Type'
FROM cases
LEFT JOIN CTE_case_parties on case_parties.case_sk =cases.case_sk
LEFT JOIN case_pic on case_pick.case_sk = cases.case_sk and group_code='CTYPE'
CROSS JOIN employee E
CROSS JOIN group_items G
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a CTE in your answer and the subqueries are completely unnecessary, i.e. you can use `... cross join Employee as E cross join Group_Items as G;`. I am curious as to whether the query optimizer puzzles out the `case` expressions to limit the cross joins or whether it just plows through it all.

Comment: @HABO I had edited the Code Now, Plz Check now.....